# Python regex isn't working on a expression

Tags: python, regex

[Regex online](https://www.regex101.com/r/hG0dE6/3#python)

Everything seems great, but on python, not so much:

```
import re 
text = "HEADER_CG_HANDSHAKE\t\t\t\t= 0xff,\n"
print(re.findall(r"[^\/](HEADER_.*)\s*?\t*?=\s*\t*((\d|[x0-9A-Fa-f])*)", text))
```

And the output is a empty list, why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
print(re.findall(r"(HEADER_.*)\s*?\t*?=\s*\t*((\d|[x0-9A-Fa-f])*)", text))
[('HEADER_CG_HANDSHAKE\t\t\t\t', '0xff', 'f')]
```

You have an extra `[^\/]` in your regex at start.

btw your `Python` input is not same as input on regex101 as leading whitespace is missing in Python code.